# React post request from react component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I have a function in React Component:

```
verifyInputAndRequest(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", this.state.username);
    formData.append("password", this.state.password);
    var reply = performPostRequest("linkRequest/", formData)
    console.log(reply) //this returns undefined     
    }

}
```

and the `performPostRequest` function looks like this:

```
export function performPostRequest(RequestUrl, data) {
    axios.post(RequestUrl, data)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        //handle error
          return error;
    });

}
```

During execution, `reply` is logged as `undefined`.

I understand this is due to synchronous execution.

How can this be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export function performPostRequest(RequestUrl, data) {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  axios.post(RequestUrl, data)
  .then(function (response) {
    resolve (response);
   })
  .catch(function (error) {
    //handle error
      reject(error);
  });
})
}
```

And in verify function :-

```
   verifyInputAndRequest(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", this.state.username);
    formData.append("password", this.state.password);
    performPostRequest("linkRequest/", formData)
     .then((data)=>{
       var reply = data;
       console.log(reply);
      })
     .catch((err)=>{
      console.log("err",err);
     })

    }

}
```